# No Monad Instance for `Data.Map`, but Scala's Map?

Tags: scala, haskell

Using `:i Map`, I don't see a `Monad` instance for it.

```
ghci> import Data.Map
ghci> :i Map
type role Map nominal representational
data Map k a
  = containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base.Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base.Size
                                         !k
                                         a
                                         !(Map k a)
                                         !(Map k a)
  | containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base.Tip
    -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Eq k, Eq a) => Eq (Map k a)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base’
instance Functor (Map k)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Ord k, Ord v) => Ord (Map k v)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Ord k, Read k, Read e) => Read (Map k e)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base’
instance (Show k, Show a) => Show (Map k a)
  -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.5.1:Data.Map.Base
```

However, I see that Scala's [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) implements `flatMap`.

I do not know if `Map` if obeys the Monad Laws.

If my observation on `Data.Map` is correct, then why isn't there an `instance Monad (Map)` in Haskell?

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973335/does-there-exist-a-monad-instance-for-data-map-data-intmap), but it looks like it uses Monad Transformers.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to reason what Scala's `flatMap` is supposed to do:

```
trait Map[A, B+] extends Iterable[(A, B)] {
  def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Map[B]
}
```

It takes a **key, value** pair of map (because flatMap comes from `Iterable`, where `A` is `(A,B)`):

```
scala> val m = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)

scala> m.flatMap (p => p match { case (_, v) => List(v, v + 3) })
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(1, 4, 2, 5)
```

This isn't monadic bind, it's more closer to `Foldable`'s `foldMap`

```
λ > import Data.Map
λ > import Data.Monoid
λ > import Data.Foldable
λ > let m = fromList [("one", 1), ("two", 2)]
λ > (\v -> [v, v + 3]) `foldMap` m
[1,4,2,5]
```

---

`Map` is lawful [`Ord k => Apply (Map k v)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-1.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html) and [`Ord k => Bind (Map k v)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-1.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Bind.html):

```
-- | A Map is not 'Applicative', but it is an instance of 'Apply'
instance Ord k => Apply (Map k) where
  (<.>) = Map.intersectionWith id
  (<. ) = Map.intersectionWith const
  ( .>) = Map.intersectionWith (const id)

-- | A 'Map' is not a 'Monad', but it is an instance of 'Bind'
instance Ord k => Bind (Map k) where
  m >>- f = Map.mapMaybeWithKey (\k -> Map.lookup k . f) m
```

Which is a bit like `ZipList` instance could be, *zipping* elements by key. *Note:* `ZipList` isn't `Bind` (only `Apply`) because you cannot remove elements from between the range.

And you cannot make it `Applicative` or `Monad`, because there are no way to make lawful `pure` / `return`, which should have a value at all keys. Or it might be possible if some `Finite` type class is constraining `k` (because `Map` is strict in it's spine, so you cannot create infinite maps).

---

*EDIT:* pointed out in the comments. If we think properly, the above tries to make a concrete (inspectable) representation of `MaybeT (Reader k) v = k -> Maybe v` with `Map k v`. But we fail, as we cannot represent `pure x = const x`. But we can try to do that by explicitly representing that case:

```
module MMap (main) where

import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Function

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

-- [[ MMap k v ]] ≅ k -> Maybe v 
data MMap k v = MConstant v
              | MPartial (Map k v)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

-- Morphism
lookup :: Ord k => k -> MMap k v -> Maybe v
lookup _ (MConstant x) = Just x
lookup k (MPartial m)  = Map.lookup k m

instance Functor (MMap k) where
  fmap f (MConstant v) = MConstant (f v)
  fmap f (MPartial m)  = MPartial (fmap f m)

instance Ord k => Applicative (MMap k) where
  pure = MConstant
  (MConstant f) <*> (MConstant x) = MConstant (f x)
  (MConstant f) <*> (MPartial x)  = MPartial (fmap f x)
  (MPartial f)  <*> (MConstant x) = MPartial (fmap ($x) f)
  (MPartial f)  <*> (MPartial x)  = MPartial (Map.intersectionWith ($) f x)

instance Ord k => Monad (MMap k) where
  return = MConstant
  (MConstant x) >>= f = f x
  (MPartial m) >>= f  = MPartial $ Map.mapMaybeWithKey (\k -> MMap.lookup k . f) m

instance (Ord k, Arbitrary k, Arbitrary v) => Arbitrary (MMap k v) where
  arbitrary = oneof [ MConstant <$> arbitrary 
                    , MPartial . Map.fromList <$> arbitrary
                    ]

prop1 :: Int -> Fun Int (MMap Int Int) -> Property
prop1 x (Fun _ f) = (return x >>= f) === f x

prop2 :: MMap Int Int -> Property
prop2 x = (x >>= return) === x

prop3 :: MMap Int Int -> Fun Int (MMap Int Int) -> Fun Int (MMap Int Int) -> Property
prop3 m (Fun _ f) (Fun _ g) = ((m >>= f) >>= g) === (m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck prop1
  quickCheck prop2
  quickCheck prop3
```

It indeed works! Yet this a bit fishy definition, as we cannot define semantically correct `Eq` instance:

```
m1 = MConstant 'a'
m2 = MPartial (Map.fromList [(True, 'a'), (False, 'a')])
```

The `m1` are `m2` are semantically equivalent (`lookup k` has same results), but structurally different. And we can't know when `MPartial` have all key-values defined.

---

Spine refers to, uh, data structure spine. For example list defined as

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

ins't strict in the spine, but

```
data SList a = SNil | SCons a !(SList a)
```

is.

You can define infinite `List`, but `SList`s:

```
λ Prelude > let l = Cons 'a' l
λ Prelude > let sl = SCons 'a' sl
λ Prelude > l `seq` ()
()
λ Prelude > sl `seq` () -- goes into infinite loop
```

As [`Map` is also strict in it's spine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-Map-Base.html#Map)

```
data Map k a  = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
              | Tip
```

we cannot construct infinite `Map`, even we had means to get all values of `k` type. But we can construct infinite ordinary Haskell list: `[]` to make `pure` for `Applicative ZipList`.

Comment: Could you please explain what `is strict in it's spine` means?

Comment: Ah, `Apply` and `Bind` are nice finds! Btw you don't have to *make* those instances, they're already given in that package :-)

Comment: @Bergi Good point, but I added them here for completeness, so one sees what they are.

Comment: I think the discussion of strictness should probably be preceded by an explanation of the essential problem: given a value but no key, the only `Map` you can make is empty, and `pure = const empty` violates the `Applicative` laws.

Comment: In your clarification of spine (thanks), `seq l () == ()` since the Weak Head Normal Form of `Cons a l` does not require evaluating `l`? Same reason that `> seq [1..] () == ()`, no?

Comment: Conal Elliott's [Denotational design with type class morphisms](http://conal.net/papers/type-class-morphisms/) discusses the design of a `Map`-alike that implements `Applicative`. I think it could also be a `Monad` on the subcategory of Hask that only contains `Semigroup` instances. (By which I mean one could probably implement a law-abiding `(>>=) :: Semigroup b => TMap k a -> (a -> TMap k b) -> TMap k b`.)

Comment: (Oops, rereading the paper it seems he even proves one can implement `Monad` without the `Semigroup` restriction! Sweet.)

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the pointer, added section about that into the answer.

Comment: @KevinMeredith maybe scala versions would help: `Cons(h: A, t: => List<A>)`, but strict is `SCons(h: A, t: List<A>)`. That (memoized) function indirection makes thing work for non-strict version.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no `Monad` instance for `Map` indeed.

> I see that Scala's Map implements `flatMap`.

I assume you notice that alone [doesn't make it a monad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27750046/1048572)?

But we can try nonetheless to make Haskell's [`Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map) a `Monad`. How would it intuitively work? We'd map over the values of the map, return a new map for each, and then `join` together all those maps by using `unions`. That should work!

Indeed, if we take a closer look at the classes that `Map` implements we see something very similar:

```
import Data.Map
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid
```

where `Monoid.mconcat` takes the role of our `unions`, and `Traversable` offers a `foldMapDefault` that does exactly what we want (and could be used for `>>=`)!

However, when we want to implement `return` we have a problem - there's no key! We get a value, but we cannot make a `Map` from that! That's the same problem Scala has avoided by making `flatMap` more generic than a monad. We could solve this by getting a default value for the key, e.g. by requiring the key type to be a `Monoid` instance, and make an `instance (Ord k, Monoid k) => Monad (Map k)` with that - but it will fail to satisfy the monad laws because of the limited `return`.

Still, all the use cases of the overloaded `flatMap` in Scala are covered by equivalent methods on Haskell `Map`s. You'll want to have a closer look at [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mapMaybe)/[`mapMaybeWithkey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mapMaybeWithKey) and [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap)/[`foldMapWithKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:foldMapWithKey).

Comment: The right identity law doesn't seem to hold: `m >>= return` for any map with non-`mempty` key. Invalid instances destroy equational reasoning, please don't make them.

Comment: @phadej: Thanks. I initially planned to incorporate a check of the monad laws in my answer, but then forgot it. I've removed the nonsense :-)

Answer (score 0):

How would you implement `return` for `Data.Map`? Presumably `return x` would have `x` as a value, but with what key(s)?

Comment: Before posting, I had this same very same question. So, from ghci, I ran `return x :: Map Int Int`

Comment: This would only work if there was a `Monad` instance, which you already know doesn't exist.